# Rails generating devise views with custom css classes template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, generator

Is it a way to generate devise views with different divs and css classes?
When I use scaffold templates I can set custom html and css classes in forms, but each time I generate a devise view I have to add those classes manually view per view.

With scaffold templates I have this file:

```
lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates/_form.html.haml
```

There I can customize html and css:

```
<% for attribute in attributes -%>
  .form-group.field-<%= attribute.name %>.field-type-<%= attribute.field_type.to_s.gsub('_', '-') %>
    = f.label I18n.t('<%= plural_table_name %>.<%= attribute.name %>'), class: 'col-sm-2 control-label'
    .col-sm-10
      = f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.name %>, class: 'form-control'
<% end -%>
  .actions
    = f.submit I18n.t('form.submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Is it a way to do this same process using templates to generate devise views with custom html and css classes?
(PD: I'm not asking how to generate views)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use platformatec's [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and create a form with custom classes (it integrates quite well with Bootstrap/Zurb Foundation).

Once you've done this, when you generate your devise views, it will detect that you are using SimpleForm and generate the views based off of the SimpleForm versions, as detailed [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Simple-Form-with-Devise).

Additionally, you can also customise the layout for the devise views (to substitute for application.html.erb) as shown [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts).